# General style for multiple dataGridView applications (General settings)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The app has multiple dataGridViews.
**Example.**
There is: dataGridView-3 pieces(dataGridView1, dataGridView2, dataGridView3).
How to do:

- dataGridView1-2 - has settings-1;
- dataGridView3 - has settings-2.

In other words, I set which "dataGridView" uses which settings.

**Question.**
How to make a common style for multiple dataGridView applications?

I created a solution.
**Result:** I get an empty UserControl

**Picture-1**
[image]

Code **MyGrid**

```
class MyGrid: DataGridView
    {
        public MyGrid ()
        {
             // this = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView ();
            // ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize) (this)). BeginInit ();
            //this.SuspendLayout ();
            //
            // dgw
            //
            this.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            // this.dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (20, 64);
            this.Name = "dgw";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (419, 173);
            // this.dgv.TabIndex = 0;
 
 
 
 
            // this.Columns ["Name"]. Width = 70; // Change the width. Field - "Name"
            // this.Columns ["Property"]. Width = 70; // Change the width. Field - "Property"
            // this.Columns [0] .Width = 70; // Change the width. Field - "Name"
            // this.Columns [1] .Width = 70; // Change the width. Field - "Property"
 
            this.RowHeadersWidth = 20; // Width "Title of rows"
            this.AllowUserToAddRows = false; // `false` - disable the line for adding a" new record "
            this.ReadOnly = true; // Editing
 
            this.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells; // Auto-fit width.
 
            this.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect; // Select the entire line
            this.MultiSelect = false; // Multi-select
            this.Columns.Cast <DataGridViewColumn> () .ToList (). ForEach (f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable); // Disable sorting
 
            // this.Size.Width = 400;
            // this.Size.Height = 170;
            
        }
 
    }
```

Code **UserControl1**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));            
 
            dt.Rows.Add("Name_1", "Property_1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name_2", "Property_2");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name_3", "Property_3");
                 
            //
            MyGrid myGrid = new MyGrid();                
            myGrid.Location = new Point(20, 64);
            myGrid.TabIndex = 0;
 
            myGrid.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Code **MainForm**

```
namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            panel1.Controls.Clear();            
            panel1.Controls.Add(userControl1);           
 
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var userControl2 = new UserControl2();
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            panel1.Controls.Add(userControl2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest method would be to create classes derived from DataGridView. Put them in a DLL, and you can access them from any application that needs these classes.

```
public class DataGridView1 : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    public DataGridView1() : base()
    {
        // Add columns, and set all styles specific for this kind of DataGridView
        this.BackColor = Colors.LightGreen;
        DataGridViewColumn columnId = new DataGridViewColumn()
        {
            Name = "columnId",
            Width = 20,
            ...
        this.Columns.Add(columnId);
        ...
    }
}

public class DataGridView1 : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    public DataGridView2() : base()
    {
        // Add columns, and set all styles specific for this kind of DataGridView
        this.BackColor = Colors.Cyan;
        DataGridViewColumn columnId = new DataGridViewColumn()
        {
            Name = "columnId",
            Width = 50,
            ...
        this.Columns.Add(columnId);
        ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly DataGridView1 dataGridView = new DataGridView1();
    ...
}
class OtherForm : Form
{
    private readonly DataGridView2 dataGridView = new DataGridView2();
    ...
}
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Thanks...
Could you help me with this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553442/how-to-display-images-in-datagridview