# How to display images in dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Description.**
It is supposed to store paths to images like `*.ico`, `*.jpg`, `*.png` in the database.
Database types:

- SQLlite;
- SQLServer;
- MySQL;

I am using `DataTable dt` to simulate the result of a `SELECT` query.

**Question.**

1. How to display images in dataGridView?
2. What is the most common practice for storing images in a database?
   Store as paths or is it better to use other options?
3. Are there any mistakes in the code?

I am running the application.
**Result:** error.
**Error:**
*Exception in DataGridView:

System.FormatException: Invalid cast "System.String" to
"System.Drawing.Image".*

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string pathProject = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dgv.CellFormatting += Dgv_CellFormatting;
    }

    private void Dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "IcoPath")
        {
            string fullpath = pathProject + e.Value.ToString();

            // e.Value = Bitmap.FromFile(fullpath);

            Image p_ImageIn = new Bitmap(fullpath);
            ImageConverter imgConverter = new ImageConverter();
            e.Value = (byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(p_ImageIn, typeof(Byte[]));
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("IcoPath", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("JpgPath", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("PngPath", typeof(string));


        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_1", @"Resources\Picture\ico\ico_1.ico");
        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_2", @"Resources\Picture\ico\ico_2.ico");
        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_3", @"Resources\Picture\ico\ico_3.ico");

        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_1", @"Resources\Picture\jpg\Jpg_1.jpg");
        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_2", @"Resources\Picture\jpg\Jpg_2.jpg");
        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_3", @"Resources\Picture\jpg\Jpg_3.jpg");

        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_1", @"\Resources\Picture\png\Png_1.png");
        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_2", @"\Resources\Picture\png\Png_2.png");
        // dt.Rows.Add("Name_3", @"\Resources\Picture\png\Png_3.png");

        dt.Rows.Add("Name_1", @"Resources\Picture\ico\ico_1.ico", @"Resources\Picture\jpg\Jpg_1.jpg", @"\Resources\Picture\png\Png_1.png");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name_2", @"Resources\Picture\ico\ico_2.ico", @"Resources\Picture\jpg\Jpg_2.jpg", @"\Resources\Picture\png\Png_2.png");
        dt.Rows.Add("Name_3", @"Resources\Picture\ico\ico_3.ico", @"Resources\Picture\jpg\Jpg_3.jpg", @"\Resources\Picture\png\Png_3.png");

        DataGridViewImageColumn icoColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        //icoColumn.HeaderText = "Image_Header";
        icoColumn.Name = "IcoPath_Name";
        icoColumn.DataPropertyName = "IcoPath";
        //// dgv.Columns.Insert(3, imageColumn);
        dgv.Columns.Add(icoColumn);

        DataGridViewImageColumn jpgColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        //icoColumn.HeaderText = "Image_Header";
        jpgColumn.Name = "JpgPath_Name";
        jpgColumn.DataPropertyName = "JpgPath";
        //// dgv.Columns.Insert(3, imageColumn);
        dgv.Columns.Add(jpgColumn);


        DataGridViewImageColumn pngColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        //icoColumn.HeaderText = "Image_Header";
        pngColumn.Name = "PngPath_Name";
        pngColumn.DataPropertyName = "PngPath";
        //// dgv.Columns.Insert(3, imageColumn);
        dgv.Columns.Add(pngColumn);


        dgv.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

**Picture-2**
[image]

---

### Update-1

When creating a solution for this issue, please do not consider images as "embedded in the project".
Application logic:

- connect to the database;
- execute the request;
- query result: `DataTable dt`;
- `DataTable dt` contains paths to images;

Comment: As you noted, you can either stored the “paths” to the images in the DB, or store the images in a `Byte[]` array format in the DB. I am not going to get into “which” is a better approach as this will depend on numerous unrelated factors. However, in you case, it appears the DB is storing the “paths” and not the actual images into the DB. The error you are getting is pretty clear…

Comment: When you manually “create” the `DataTable` the image columns are of type `string`… `dt.Columns.Add("JpgPath", typeof(string));` … therefore, when you map the `DataGridViewImageColumn` to the `DataColumn` in the `DataTable` with… `jpgColumn.DataPropertyName = "JpgPath";` … this will fail and give you the error you see since the data in the `DataTable` is of type `string` and the `DataGridViewImageColumn` is obviously going to be looking for something like a `Byte[]` array. In this case, you will need to get the actual images to bind them to the grid’s “image” columns.

Comment: @JohnG Summary.
**1.** `dataGridView` cannot display images (`*.ico`, `*.jpg`, `*.png`) using only image paths.
**2.** If `DataTable dt` contains only paths to images (`*.ico`, `*.jpg`, `*.png`), then in order to display images in the `dataGridView`, it is necessary to convert images to `Byte []`.
**3.** Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Changing the image columns in the `DataTable` to type `Image` or `Byte[]` array. Then get the “actual” images from the resources and convert them to either an `Image` or `Byte[]` array and it should display the images properly. To get the image... something like...  `Image img = Image.FromFile(@"Path to image.jpg");`

Comment: Answers to your questions… 1) correct, the grid is not going to go and get the image and convert it for you. 2) correct, if the DB only has the paths, then your code is going to have to go and get the images.

Comment: @JohnG **1.** *2) correct, if the DB only has the paths, then your code is going to have to go and get the images.* If so, then I have to execute the next solution.
**Decision**
**-** I get a `DataTable dt` with image paths.
**-** I execute `foreach (var item in collection) {}` to get images based on their paths and convert the images to ʻImage` or `Byte []`.
**Output**
This solution will slow down the application. It is more rational to store pictures in the database in the format `Byte []`.
**2.** Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Simple example: `dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = someFilePath;
 dataGridView1[1, 0].Value = (Image)Image.FromFile(dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString());` - Also: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netcore-3.1) : _The CellFormatting event occurs every time each cell is painted, so you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event._ - So try to call the assignment __only once__ and not in a __recurring__ event !!

Comment: As I stated previously, storing the image path or the image itself into the DB is something you may want to discuss with your DB manager. If there are many pictures, it is not unusual to store the string paths in the DB, and the actual images somewhere else, however, I will often store the images directly in the DB in order to avoid this extra step. Again, that is different question.

Comment: @TaW I don't understand how to apply your solution to my case.
How to apply your solution, could you describe in more detail for my case?
Will it be like something like this? (see below)  `DataGridViewImageColumn icoColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();            
icoColumn.Name = "IcoPath_Name";
icoColumn.DataPropertyName = (Image)Image.FromFile(dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString()); ???
icoColumn.Image = ???
dgv.Columns.Add(icoColumn);`

Comment: Hm, do you want all rows to show the same image? If not you need to set the values of the Cells, not of the Column! One way or other you will need a loop that set the values of all image cells. Btw: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789466/showing-image-in-a-datagridviewimagecolumn-binding-text-field) is an example that uses the CellFormatting event (as a loop) but with a check to avoid setting an image multiple times..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, since the images are NOT coming from a DB but are embedded in the project as shown from the solution explorer picture, your code is going to have to “build” this `DataTable` using those embedded resources.

Is what it appears you are trying to do is “add” the pictures to the grids “column.” You want to add the images to the `DataTable` ROWS. Then, it will be unnecessary to “add” the “grid image” column to the grid. The grid will know how to display the images from the `DataTable` since they are “actual” images.

Below is a small example with only one image column, however it should not be difficult to add the other columns using the same strategy. Also, I am getting the images that are embedded as a resource in the project as your current picture shows. You will need to change the text that says “ProjectName” with the name of your project in addition to the image file names.

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("JpgPath", typeof(Image));

  Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.Resources.Picture.jpg.image1.jpg");
  Image jpg1 = new Bitmap(myStream);
  myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.Resources.Picture.jpg.image2.jpg");
  Image jpg2 = new Bitmap(myStream);
  myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.Resources.Picture.jpg.image3.jpg");
  Image jpg3 = new Bitmap(myStream);

  dt.Rows.Add("Name1", jpg1);
  dt.Rows.Add("Name2", jpg2);
  dt.Rows.Add("Name3", jpg3);

  dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Edit from OP question.

The example below shows two methods. The first is a simulation of getting the data from the DB where the images are not there but the string paths to the images are.

Once we have the `DataTable` from the DB, we need to “add” those images to each row in the existing `DataTable`. Obviously, we need to “add” the new “Image” column to the existing `DataTable` we got from the DB. Then loop through each row and add the image to the image column based on the path in that row.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataTable DBTable = GetTableFromDB();
  AddImageColumnToDT(DBTable);
  dgv.DataSource = DBTable;
}


private DataTable GetTableFromDB() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("ImagePath", typeof(string));
  dt.Rows.Add("Name1", "PathTo_Image1");
  dt.Rows.Add("Name2", "PathTo_Image2");
  dt.Rows.Add("Name3", "PathTo_Image3");
  return dt;
}

private void AddImageColumnToDT(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(Image));
  string curPath;
  Image curImage;
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    curPath = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
    curImage = Image.FromFile(curPath);
    row["Image"] = curImage;
  }
}
```

EDIT*** if the DB returns a "empty" `byte[]` array column instead of an `Image` type.

```
private DataTable GetTableFromDB2() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("ImagePath", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(byte[]));
  dt.Rows.Add("Name1", "PathTo_Image1");
  dt.Rows.Add("Name2", "PathTo_Image2");
  dt.Rows.Add("Name3", "PathTo_Image3");
  return dt;
}

private void AddImageColumnToDT2(DataTable dt) {
  //dt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(byte[]));
  string curPath;
  Image curImage;
  byte[] curByteArray;
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    curPath = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
    curImage = Image.FromFile(curPath);
    curByteArray = imageToByteArray(curImage);
    row["Image"] = curByteArray;
  }
}

public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn) {
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: See Update-1
Additionally quote: "I am using` DataTable dt` to simulate the result of a SELECT query. "
Sorry ... I'm already confused ... I don't remember why I included images in the project.

Comment: Well look at it this way… 1) if the “images” are stored in the DB, then that is all you need to do, simply get the `DataTable` from the DB and use it as a `DataSource` to the grid… it will know how to handle the actual images and there will be no need to add the `DataGridViewImageColumns` to the grid.

Comment: 2) If the DB only stores the string “path” to the images, then your code is going to have to add those “images” to the data tables rows in some fashion. Example, you get the data table from the DB, it has the string paths for the images… then, create a new “image” column to the existing data table, loop through the rows, on each row grab the sting image path, get the image and then add that image to the new image column cell on that row. Does that make sense?

Comment: @climivin Please see my edit that shows a small example of what I described in my previous comments.

Comment: **1.** `2) ... Does this make sense?`
Didn't understand your question .... But if I understood the point correctly: loop through the rows is required.

Comment: **2.** Solution-1. My.
This solution is used in order not to store the image in the database table.
**Conditions** - there is a database; - table `Table-1`; Fields:
- `PathIMJ` - type: string;
- `IMJ` - type: `byte[]`; (spare field. in this table this field is not filled in)

Comment: **Logics:**
- connect to the database;
- execute the `SELECT` query;
- result: `DataTable dt` with data from the table `Table-1`;
 - loop through the rows `DataTable dt` using logic: - get the value of the field `PathIMJ`; - get an image; - put the image in the `IMJ` field (`DataTable dt`).
**Question:** do you think such a decision is permissible or is it complete nonsense?
I have little experience ... Plus I'm completely confused ...

Comment: **3.** From all of the above, I realized that loop through the rows is required anyway.
And I don't like it ...
Although maybe this is a normal practice and I'm just exaggerating? **4.** When we execute the instruction `DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable`
What's going on?
Loop through the rows?
All `dataGridView` cells are equal to` dataTable` cells
For example: - dataGridView1 [i, i] .Value = dataTable [i, i] .Value

Comment: **5.** Condition: the table will contain 10,000 - 100,000 rows.
In this case, `foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {// ...}` will slow down the application?
A solution using simply `DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable` will work faster?
Which exit? Do pagination (loading data by page)?

Comment: If the images are NOT stored in the Db and the paths are, I am not sure how you would expect to “automatically” get those images without some extra code and execution time. As I mentioned earlier, if the images ARE in the DB, then you do not have to do anything. It certainly is something you need to consider i.e. a tradeoff to execution time which should be quicker if the pictures are in the DB and possibly adding huge images to the DB. IMHO, in either case, I don’t think the execution times would be that big a difference, however I could be wrong about that.

Comment: _”When we execute the instruction DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable What's going on?”_ This will “automatically” set up the proper “grid” column types from the data table column types. I am betting you are confused as it appears you are “looking” at the “GRID” to loop through rows etc.… NO… “everything” I discussed is done on the `DATATABLE` (not the grid). This is done “before” we set the data table as a data source to the grid. If we set up the data table correctly, we will not have to do anything to the grid other than possibly making the path column invisible.

Comment: If you have 100,000 rows, then I would do some testing first and see how it goes. If its to slow, then pagination or lazy loading may be an option, unfortunately this is getting off course from the original question and there are many things you can do to speed up things when there is a lot of data. I would test it. And if it is slow, try some things and if that doesn’t work, post another question.

Comment: ** 1. ** Could you please respond to comments that start with phrases:
- `2. Solution-1.`;
- `Logics:` (this is a continuation of the comment `2. Solution-1.`);
** 2. ** If you think my question is useful, I would be grateful if you put - "+".

Comment: 2. Solution-1… I am guessing that the field `IMJ` is “empty? If so, then… If the table you get back from the DB already has a `byte[]` field named `IMJ` and it is an “empty” field, then using the `AddImageColumnToDt` method, comment out the part that adds the image column (since we already have it) and also change the column identifiers when getting the path and when setting the image to the cell. Using your example… `curPath = row["ImagePath"].ToString();` would be changed to. `curPath = row["PathIMJ"].ToString();` and `row["IMJ"] = curImage;` … 2. Will Do.

Comment: My images go beyond the cells.
I used `((DataGridViewImageColumn)dgv.Columns [2]).ImageLayout`.
The complete code looks like this `((DataGridViewImageColumn)dgv.Columns [2]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;`
**Question:** Is my solution acceptable or are there other more rational ways?